# Bot triggers itself with a command

Tags: javascript, bots

While I was coding a command for my bot:

```
client.on('message', message=> {
    if (message.content.valueOf('ip'))
        message.channel.send(
            "Our Server IP is `blank` For Java. For Bedrock it is `blank` and port `blank`."
        )
});
```

The bot would auto reply to itself. Is there any piece of code I can add to make it not do this?

Fixed: replaced .valueOf to .includes

Comment: if it is possible check who the message is coming from, from the player/user or the bot along with the contents

Comment: You’re probably looking for `message.content.includes('ip')`, not `valueOf`. (This is case-sensitive, so it also happens to “fix” the problem, but you should fix it the right way separately.)

Answer (score 0):

The code `if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;` checks if the message's author is the same as client's user (your bot) and skips the rest of the code.